# Iframe-resizer JS Library: Child Anchor Link Not Working w. iFrame Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, iframe-resizer

Using the amazing **[Iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)** JavaScript library by David J. Bradshaw. A cross domain iFrame that contains a form, is correctly being downsized after form submission. However the parent page does not follow the anchor link inside the child, which is redirecting submissions to the top of the form container.

Therefore the contained iFrame moves out of position, or even outside of vision.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./iframeResizer.min.js"></script>

<iframe src="http://www.childiframe.com/form/" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

<script>jQuery('iframe').iFrameResize({moveToAnchor:('top')});</script>
```

Is there a way to have the parent page follow the redirected anchor link of the (iFramed) child page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In page linking is set to false by default. By enabling the **inPageLinks** option, anchor links within the child page are automatically followed by the parent. This script is genius!

```
<script>jQuery('iframe').iFrameResize({inPageLinks:true});</script>
```